# Migrating hard drives, without windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, lubuntu

Okay, so I’m finally ready to ditch both Windows 7 and my aging 5400 RPM hard drive in an old laptop. It currently is 640 gigs. I bought myself a 500 gig Crucial SSD. So I started to migrate like I would on windows. I installed a fresh copy of lubuntu 22.04 (same as installed on the hard disk) on the SSD, figuring it would setup the boot record, format the drive, and just to confirm the SSD was good. Everything worked.

I used a Sata to USB adapter I’ve used to clone windows drives before, and used DiskGenius, a program I’ve also used before to clone Windows, and wrote the lubuntu partition from the 5400 rpm drive, dev/sda3, to the SSD, making it dev/sda1.

Well in retrospect, this was a pretty obvious mistake, I’m assuming the grub list thinks lubuntu is on sda3 when it’s actually on sda1 where windows used to be, because lubuntu boots to the splash screen and hangs half a second after starting to load. Basically, how do I fix this boneheaded move. The platter drive still works so it’s not like I’m completely SOL, but I would love to use this fancy new SSD.

I tried the boot-repair from a live instance of lubuntu, that didn’t work, it reports being unable to find the grub2 repositories. I also tried it manually with the guide here:

https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Grub reports it reinstalls, and indeed the drive boots, but same issue. If I select Ubuntu from the grub menu, it hangs a second after showing the splash screen.

Basically, I wanted my partition map to be as simple as possible, just let Lubuntu take the whole drive, no boot partition, no windows, just lubuntu on dev/sda.

I’m fairly new with all this so any help would be appreciated. Assuming I cannot fix the current SSD partitioning, I’m fine wiping it since as stated the hard disk is still good and booting. What is the correct way to migrate just lubuntu to the SSD?

Clarification: This machine predates EFI (hence using lubuntu). DiskGenius did copy the UUID correctly from the hard disk to the SSD per `blkid`

Comment: You didn't mention if your device is uEFI/Secure-uEFI in boot; as that will require an ESP (*Efi System Partition*) to exist for boot to occur; Lubuntu uses a *single* partition ONLY if BIOS install is used. A normal install won't rely on sdaX partitions, but UUID's or unique ID's of partitions which can change on 'copy/move' (not generally if entire drive is cloned though). Please clarify details (did you check UUIDs matched? `blkid` etc)

Comment: FYI:  All of Ubuntu releases will install and run on any device (not just Lubuntu). Lubuntu's install defaults to no ESP where none are detected at boot, thus how ISO was written to installation media can influence if it's required (ie. an install from the same ISO to different drives can result in different types of partitions being created **if** the *identical* ISO was written differently to media for each install; if you didn't use the same thumb-drive for both - you should confirm yourself by comparing partition(s)).

Comment: Ensure you don't have two partitions with the same UUID.unique-ID as that **will** create problems.

Comment: Might have found the issue, a case of me not paying attention. Original drive has an msdos partition table. SSD has a GPT. Reformatting and trying again, cloned the UUID with `tune2fs` and in the middle of `dd if=/dev/sdc3 of=/dev/sda1` which I anticipate to take quite some time.

Comment: IF gpt, you cannot easily use dd to clone a partition. GUID entries are in primary partition table, partition & backup partition table. You can and should use gpt, I have since 2010 and then it was only BIOS. But with BIOS boot you need a tiny 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR Best just to do new install & restore using rsync from your normal backups.

Answer (score 0):

Fix
Okay, so here are the steps I took to get Lubuntu migrated to a new SSD without the windows partition.

I formatted the SSD as ext4 being sure to use the msdos partition table. I used tune2fs to clone the UUID off the old partition. I then installed a fresh copy of Lubuntu 22.04 (same live usb instance that I used to originally install the OS).

After rebooting, I booted back into the Live USB instance. I copied the /boot/ directory off the SSD. I then again formatted and copied to UUID off the original hard disk.

I then shrank the original hard disk ext4 partition as much as possible in gparted after unmounting the partition so dd didn’t take a million hours. I then used dd to copy the Lubuntu instance to the new SSD. Finally, I deleted the /boot/ directory and copied the /boot/ directory off the live usb instance to the SSD.

There was probably a much easier way to do this, but this worked and I’ve since devoted the old hard disk in a usb enclosure to make full image backups so it should be much easier to do this later if I need to.